# Custom Route using Attribute Routing in WebApi

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm working on retrieving list of Movie Details from DB using WebAPi. I've http verbs and it does work as normal. I've a scenario where i've to get records based on categories like `Title`, `Date`, `Rating`
**WebConfig:**

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, action = "ActionName" }
```

**Controller :**

```
[HttpGet]
[GET("api/GetMovieByCategory/{movieData}")]
public IEnumerable<MovieData> GetMovieByCategory(MovieData movieData)  
    {
        IEnumerable<MovieData> movieDataByCat = null;
        string[] paramCast;
        if(movieData.Cast.Count()!=0)
        paramCast = movieData.Cast;
        IEnumerable<MovieData> GetAllMovies = null;
        GetAllMovies = repo.GetAll();`

        if (movieData.Cast == null || movieData.Cast.Count() == 0)
        {
            movieDataByCat = from data in GetAllMovies
                             where (data.Classification == (movieData.Classification == null ? string.Empty : movieData.Classification) ||
                                    data.Genre == (movieData.Genre == null ? string.Empty : movieData.Genre) ||
                                    data.Rating == movieData.Rating ||
                                    data.ReleaseDate == movieData.ReleaseDate ||
                                    data.Title == (movieData.Title == null ? string.Empty : movieData.Title))

                             select data;
        }
        return movieDataByCat;
    }
```

**Angular Service :**

```
//GetByCategory
this.getbyCat = function (Movie) {
    return $http.get("/api/values/GetMovieByCategory/" + Movie);
};
```

when i try to execute, i'm getting an exception as follows,

```
Remote Address:[::1]:50948
Request URL:http://localhost:50948/api/values/GetMovieByCategory/[object%20Object]
Request Method:GET
Status Code:404 Not Found
```

I've no idea how to overcome this and get it resolved. I'm in beginner level. Please help.

Rest of all verbs `(get,put,post)` are working fine.

**Note :** I've installed NugetPackage `AttributeRouting.Web.Http;` for `Route`.

**Update 1 :**
`Contoller.js` :
`$scope.srchbycat = function () {
        var Movie = {
            _title:"",
            _genre: "",
            _classification:"",
            _releaseDate: "",
            _rating: "",
            _cast: ""
        };
        Movie = {
            _title: $scope.txttitle,
            _genre: $scope.txtGenre,
            _classification: $scope.txtClassification,
            _releaseDate: $scope.txtDate,
            _rating: $scope.user.txtRating,
            _cast: $scope.txtCast
        };
        var promisePost = MyService.getbyCat(Movie);`

**Recent Error :**
`Remote Address:[::1]:50948
Request URL:http://localhost:50948/api/values/GetMovieByCategory/?_genre=sdf
Request Method:GET
Status Code:400 Bad Request`

Comment: try this `var movie = JSON.stringify({ movieData: Movie }); return $http.get("/api/values/GetMovieByCategory/" + movie )`

Comment: currently `{movieData}` is expecting a string, if you are passing it some non default(string) type of variable you need to tell it what to expect.

Comment: @Akshay
i tried but got this,
`Remote Address:[::1]:50948  
Request     URL:http://localhost:50948/api/values/GetMovieByCategory/%7B%22movieData%22:%7B%22_genre%22:%22sdfsdf%22,%22_rating%22:%22%22%7D%7D  
Request Method:GET  
Status Code:400 Bad Request`

Answer (score 1):

In the Angular Service, instead of appending the Movie object, pass it as parameter.

eg.

```
//GetByCategory
this.getbyCat = function (Movie) {
    return $http.get("/api/values/GetMovieByCategory/", { params: Movie});
};
```

This will make the HTTP get with the the properties as url parameters.

And I dont think there is a need for the {movieData} parameter in the Route defined, since WebApi will automatically Serialize the url parameters to the object MovieData

eg.

index.js

```
angular.module('index.services', []).
factory('indexService', function ($http) {
      var api = 'api/values/GetData';
      var indexAPI = {};

      indexAPI.getData = function (params) {
          return $http.get(api, { params: params });
      }

      return indexAPI;
});
angular.module('index.controllers', ['index.services']).
controller('indexController', function ($scope, indexService) {
    $scope.getData = function () {
        var params = {
            name: 'test',
            age: '10'
        };
        $scope.errorOccured = false;
        indexService.getData(params).then(function (response) {
            $scope.data = response.data;
        }, function (response) {
            $scope.errorOccured = true;
        });
    }
});
angular.module('index', ['index.controllers']);
```

Index.cshtml

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-beta.1/angular.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/app/index.js"></script>
<div ng-app="index" ng-controller="indexController">
    <button ng-click="getData()">Get Data</button>
    <div ng-if="errorOccured==true">Error Occured</div>
    <div ng-repeat="item in data">
        <div>{{item}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

DataRequestModel.cs

```
public class DataRequestModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Age { get; set; }
}
```

ValuesController.cs

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> GetData([FromUri]DataRequestModel dataRequest)
    {
        return new string[] { dataRequest.Name, dataRequest.Age.ToString() };
    }
}
```

Comment: i've modified my route in APIController as 
`[HttpGet]`  
`[GET("api/GetMovieByCategory/")]`
But still getting following exception on Submit,  
`Request URL:http://localhost:50948/api/values/GetMovieByCategory/?_classification=sdf&_rating=
Request Method:GET
Status Code:400 Bad Request`

Comment: Try removing the '/' at the end of the route. What are the properties in the C# class MovieData? The url parameters should exactly match the property names inside MovieData for the binding to occur properly.

Comment: Well it works half way. I could see the values which are being entered are there in `Movie` params in `Service`, but when it hits ApiController, MovieData is null.....what could be the reason?

Comment: Make sure the [FromUri] attribute is specified on the Action for the MovieData and the names of the properties match the url parameters. public IEnumerable<MovieData> GetMovieByCategory([FromUri] MovieData movieData)

Comment: I afraid I'm not getting it exactly. could you please point me broad

Comment: can you pass some `id` kind of thing to get the data instead of sending the entire object? That would simplify the things